# Add span tag dynamically to certain words in content editable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have created a content editable div where users can write comments and tag other users. As the user types, an API call will be made to check any username is specified in the comment.

Example if someone writes: 
"**This task will be handled by User123. UserABC and UserXYZ can help.**"

Here is the API response:

```
res = [
    {'useremail':"user123@email.com", "start":29, "end": 36},
    {'useremail':"userxyz@email.com", "start":38, "end": 45},
    {'useremail':"userabc@email.com", "start":50, "end": 57}
]
```

If no user name found, the response will be an empty array.

Now the problem is while adding the span tags for those user names specified in the comments to highlight them. I know the start and end index of the text content to highlight. How can I dynamically add the span tags to the given indexes in the editable div? The process should not interrupt the user who is typing.

I prefer to use pure Javascript for this. But I am okay with using jQuery.

Any help is appreciated. 
Please comment if you need more information. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would just get the text, cut it, truncate the div and append span wrappers with specific text chunks. It shouldn't interrupt the user.

Also if you call `innerText` you will get the text of all descendants therefore even if they are in span wrappers you can extract the whole text and recut it.

Comment: Thanks, @rok-burgar. But I didn't get what you said. Do you mean to say I should replace the innerHTML of the div? Could you please elaborate, or provide some code if possible?